# Selecting the most common value from relation - SQL statement

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table within my database that has many records, some records share the same value for one of the columns. e.g.

```
|  id  |  name  |  software  |
______________________________
|  1   |  john  |  photoshop |
|  2   |  paul  |  photoshop |
|  3   |  gary  |  textmate  |
|  4   |  ade   |  fireworks |
|  5   |  fred  |  textmate  |
|  6   |  bob   |  photoshop |
```

I would like to return the value of the most common occurring piece of software, by using an SQL statement.

So in the example above the required SQL statement would return 'photoshop' as it occurs more than any other piece of software.

Is this possible?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Ronnie : which version of database are you using? MySQL? Oracle ?

Comment: Sorry, I am using MySQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get most common value in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344665/get-most-common-value-in-sql)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
select top 1 software 
from your_table 
group by software
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: Thanks Carl, what does the 'top 1' part mean? thanks for your quick response.

Comment: @Ronnie it returns from the top of the matches from the query, which in this case are descending, the # of records indicated

Comment: So, this statement will order all of the records in groups starting with the group of the most common software and the descending. But the 'top 1' selects just the value from the first group?

Comment: I have tested this statement on the table using phpmyadmin and it returns an error stating 'You have an error in your SQL syntax'?

Comment: +1 For MySQL, remove `top 1`, and add `limit 1` at the end, behind the `order by`

Comment: @Andomar Perfect, that works a treat, thanks for your comment and Carl.

Answer (score 4):

It depends if you want to use standard SQL or vendor specific extensions (another poster has a "top N" query which is *not* standard). A standard solution would be.

```
SELECT software, COUNT(1) 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY software
HAVING COUNT(1) = (
  SELECT MAX(sc) FROM (
    SELECT software, COUNT(1) sc
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY software
  )
)
```

**Note:** this may return multiple rows if several pieces of software are tied for the most occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways but the simplest way would be this

```
SELECT item  
FROM (SELECT item FROM your_table GROUP BY item ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc)  
WHERE ROWNUM<=1;
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `ROWNUM`.